# A bitmap gets loaded, another bitmap doesn't. LoadImage() from Windows.h

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, loadimage

I have two bitmaps. The first one is named BM1, the second one is named BM2.
I wrote this line of code in the WM_CREATE message case:

```
HBITMAP hImage = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "C://Projects/BM1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

If i attempt to load BM1, it works. 
If i attempt to load BM2, the function returns NULL.

This is the difference in the data of those images: 
BM1 (the good one) is 34 x 34. Bit depth 4. Size 798 bytes. 
BM2 (the bad one) is 272 x 290. Bit depth 24. Size 234 kilobyte (It was a png and i converted it to bmp).

I assume the problem is (almost) obviously related to the bit depth, but i would like to understand why. I'm using the x64 configuration.

Comment: A couple of observations. Quoting the [documentation of `LoadImageA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea): _"To load a predefined image or a standalone resource (icon, cursor, or bitmap file), set this parameter to `NULL`."_ Thus, don't invoke `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`, give it just `NULL` as the first parameter. Another quote: _"If the function fails, the return value is `NULL`. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`."_ So, if you receive `NULL`, you should immediately call `GetLastError()`. What value does `GetLastError()` return?

Comment: Another thought: you say it was a PNG and you converted it to BMP. But how did you convert it, what software did you use? For example, it seems that in GIMP you need to explicitly specify the _"Do not write color space information"_ option, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/scypg.png

Comment: Could it be that the first image was valid and the second one was not? Easiest explanation...

Comment: You don't need the double `//` after `C:`. One will do.

Comment: The core issue is in the tool you used to convert BM2 failing to produce a valid BMP file. This is rather common. The quick solution: Load BM2 into MS Paint, and without changing a thing, save it from there. That gets you a valid BMP file.

Comment: You can't convert a PNG to a BMP just by changing the file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) said: *The core issue is in the tool you used to convert BM2 failing to produce a valid BMP file.*

You can convert it to BMP file by **Microsoft Paint** correctly.
[image]

You can set depth in here.

[image]

Comment: Yes i noticed, i "reconverted" the bmp file with paint and now it works. The first time i used one of those online converters and it turns out it didn't work out properly. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @NicholasFresta Accpet the wiki if you can do. Thank you for that for community.